# How can i download tensorflow tf_files

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying Tensorflow for poets and I can not download the example files. 
     `curl http://download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz \
    | tar xz -C tf_files`

Comment: Were you able to download the `tf_files` in the TensorFlow For Poets course?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using cURL doesn't work try using `http://download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz`
in the address bar of your browser. The file should download automatically or you should be prompted.

Then just create the `tf_files` directory locally:

```
mkdir tf_files
```

Finally extract:

```
tar -xzf flower_photos.tgz -C tf_files
```